# How could I get the date in jQuery through timezone

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, frontend

I have a code that calculates next Monday and sends a link to the user, however if the user advances the calendar, receives the video before everyone else.

How could I get the date in jQuery through timezone, without giving the user the chance to change the date on the computer and cheat everything?

Comment: `cheat everything` what do you mean?

Comment: I have a code where he calculates next Monday and sends a link to the user, however if he advances the calendar he receives the video before everyone else

Comment: You can always use libraries like [moment timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) IF you know in which timezone your users are at.

Comment: @LuizFelipe I've added your comment's info in the question. You can also **[edit]** it to add more info and/or adjust it accordingly. e.g. it'd be good to have the code you're using, some examples of inputs and outputs and so on - in other words, a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question but if you just want the current date through jQuery you can use:

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', new Date());
```

Note: you will need [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/) for this.